# How to prevent Laravel 5.8 from caching controllers

Tags: caching, controller, laravel-5.8

After moving from an AWS Linux 2/Apache server to Ubuntu 14.2/NGINX Laravel controller output is being cached.

When updating code in a controller and saving it consistently takes 30+ seconds before the new changes are reflected in the browser. I created a test function with a controller and included a random string to see if the web output from the controller was being cached or the controller code itself. When refreshing the page in rapid succession the random string always changes, but if I update a static output it does not change.

Here's are the steps

**1. Call function below from a route to the controller where it lives.**

```
`public static function test_function() {
    echo(str_random(32));
    echo('<br>Line 1');
    //echo('<br>Line 2');
}`
```

Browser output:

d3SomhsJ0KfUKgvd1aSwwzI3d0y8w0Zx
   
Line 1

**2. Uncomment `echo('<br>Line 2');` and save file.**

Refreshed output:

6BZCh9xbvvYFUz1uOQP8wCyDQxfrFblU
   
Line 1

**3. After 30 seconds**

Refreshed output:

xpKXULHxWmTIrcneESKEJHDn4AO3HthV
   
Line 1
   
Line 2

Sometimes it takes closer to 40 seconds.

Making updates to controllers and testing is now taking forever.

Here's what I've tried to fix problem to no avail:
run command `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`
Changed `opcache.revalidate_freq=30` value to 0 in php.in then restarted nginx

Help!

Comment: Restarting the server fixed this issue.